# PHP used in drupal. Printing using a variable

Tags: php, drupal

I have the following code:

```
print $node->field_carousel_1[0]['filepath'];
```

What i would like to do is change the 1 and use a variable instead.

Do you have any idea how i would be able to do this?

What i am aiming for: Using a variable instead of the one to create a looping function to print field_carousel_1, field_carousel_2, field_carousel_3 etc

Comment: Told to post this on here instead of drupal site :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++) {
  $field = "field_carousel_$i";
  $arr = $node->$field;
  print $arr[0]['filepath'];
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better? `print $node->$field[0]['filepath'];`

Comment: @VladStratulat doesn't work, at least not for me. `$field[0]` is evaluated first, so you'll get an error that `$node->f` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would store these in an array.

```
field_carousel=array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'etc.')
```

To print them, you would do...

```
foreach(field_carousel as $item) {
  echo $item
  }
```